# Using a different domain name

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2010

I configured the FQDN of a server to xyz.local and NetBIOS is xyz,

What I want to ask is; can the server be configured to host an exchange server for a different name say abc.com

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

---

Answers must be at least 30 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `xyz.local` is an Active Directory domain, of which the server is a member; also, I'm assuming `abc.com` is a SMTP domain, for which you want your Exchange server to handle email delivery.

If this is the case, then yes, this is a perfectly valid configuration; it's also standard practice: usually your internal Active Directory domain and your public domain (for which Exchange handles email delivery) do not match, and they should not, because it can create lots of issues when they do.